# Why does light position not update?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js to render a moving cylinder:

```js
let renderer, camera, scene, light, cylinder;

initialize();
animate();

function initialize() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.SpotLight();
  scene.add(light);

  cylinder = new THREE.Mesh();
  cylinder.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: "#007700" });
  cylinder.geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 3, 12, 25)
  scene.add(cylinder);
}

function animate() {
  cylinder.position.z -= 1;
  cylinder.rotation.x -= THREE.Math.degToRad(2);
  
  light.position.x = cylinder.position.x;
  light.position.y = cylinder.position.y + 100;
  light.position.z = cylinder.position.z;

  camera.position.x = cylinder.position.x;
  camera.position.y = cylinder.position.y + 10;
  camera.position.z = cylinder.position.z + 30;
  camera.lookAt(cylinder.position);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: #aaccaa;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.js">
</script>
```

I want the light to be positioned above the cylinder every frame, but as you can see the cylinder quickly moves into darkness. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such thing happens when you don't set the spotlight's target.

The documentation says:

*.target*

*The Spotlight points from its position to target.position. The default position of the target is (0, 0, 0).*

*Note: For the target's position to be changed to anything other than the default, it must be added to the scene using*

Thus, it means that when you move your light with the cylinder, it (the light) points to the center of the scene, as it's a default.

Assign your cylinder as the light's target and you'll get the desired result.

```js
let renderer, camera, scene, light, lightPosition, cylinder;

initialize();
animate();

function initialize() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  cylinder = new THREE.Mesh();
  cylinder.material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ color: "#007700" });
  cylinder.geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(3, 3, 12, 25)
  scene.add(cylinder);
  
  light = new THREE.SpotLight();
  lightPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 100, 0);
  light.target = cylinder;
  scene.add(light);
}

function animate() {
  cylinder.position.z -= 1;
  cylinder.rotation.x -= THREE.Math.degToRad(2);
  
  light.position.copy(cylinder.position).add(lightPosition);

  camera.position.x = cylinder.position.x;
  camera.position.y = cylinder.position.y + 10;
  camera.position.z = cylinder.position.z + 30;
  camera.lookAt(cylinder.position);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: #aaccaa;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.js">
</script>
```